# $(opener.document).find('.target').css('display') not working in explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

In parent(iframe),

```
<tr class="target" style="display:none;">
    <td class="label">Test</td>
</tr>
```

In popup,

```
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var target = $(opener.document).find('.target').css('display');
    if(target == "none"){
        ...
    }
});
<script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

As above, the display value of the parent window is fetched from the popup window. But, it is not working in IE. In IE the display value is "undefined".
In Chrome, however, it is normally set to "none".

How can I get that display value from the popup window in IE?

+++

One thing I missed is the popup window that is opened through the iframe.

So there is a parent window, in which there is a iframe, and a popup window opens in that iframe. I want to get the display value of the iframe from the popup window.

Comment: Are the popup and parent both the same domain? If not, it sounds like IE's default security settings won't allow access to `opener.document`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Naturally, the two domains are the same.

Comment: When I try to fetch it using JavaScript, I get the display value normally.
`opener.document.getElementById('target').style.display;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your target document as the context of jQuery's function. You can do so using the second parameter of [*$(selector, context)*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

So for you it would be

```
var target = $('.target', opener.document).css('display');
```

But IE has a weird bug where `opener.getComputedStyle()`'s values will all be set to `null`.

So the only way I found to workaround that is to load jQuery in the `opener` itself, and from your popup to call its own `jQuery` function:

```
var target = opener.$('.target').css('display');
```

[Live plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TE6h5j16fwosH21bPycH?p=preview).

Comment: Unfortunately, since you answered, I tried to fix it, but IE also gets undefined.

Comment: Han... And only on IE right? Could you try to set up a **minimal** example on a service like https://plnkr.co so we can see wht happens exactly.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/CNq0NccjjgAUGpu6o94r/   <= Check this url. I made small sample. In this small sample too, Chrome will get the correct value, but in IE it will get "undefined".